# Styling a web page issue using react

Tags: css, reactjs

[webpage[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkFU0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYb97.png

I have an issue with styling with this webpage. my h1 tag with the data is being displayed in the header . See the image that is attached. Is there a way to fix this?

[React.js and css      .header {
width: 100%;
height: 5rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: #77002e;
padding: 0 10%;
}

```
 .logo {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

 .header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
```

}

```
 .header li {
  margin-left: 3rem;
```

}

```
 .header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 1.5rem;
 color: #fcb8d2;
}

 .header a:hover,
 .header a:active,
 .header a.active {
  color: white;
```

}

```
.badge {
 background-color: #cc2062;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 12px;
 padding: 0 1rem;
 margin-left: 0.5rem;
}]`
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi52m.png)